# using command "adb shell install" and showing "install: not found"

Tags: android, adb

I'm using command `adb shell install xxx.apk` to install an APK on the emulator, however, it shows

> /system/bin/sh: install: not found

I have done this for many times and today it suddenly fails.

I have read some similar questions on StackOverflow but they can't solve my questions. I have set my SDK path and I just start one avd.

Comment: Somehow I doubt that you had done it before like you claim. Because it is not `adb shell install` - it's `adb install`

Comment: `shell` doesn't have `install`. `adb` has it

Comment: Also see: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#move for how to install from ADB.

Comment: @AlexP. Oh yes. I think I have made a foolish mistake. As I have used `adb` and `adb shell` a lot recently, I just confuse them. Thank you for patience. @AlexP.@Vladyslav Matviienko@Darwind

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue to solve it I separate the shell command.

1. Type `adb shell` or `adb -e shell` to target the emunator
2. You should see something like `generic_x86_64_arm64:/ $` and type your shell command now. In your example `install xxx.apk`
3. to quit, type `exit`